# Field position limit in Sphinx to *start* search at character position?

Tags: sphinx

As far as I can tell "Field position limit" in sphinx only allows you to force search to the first N characters in a document? Is there anyway to use it to force search AFTER the first N characters instead?

```
The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog and he was crazy as a fox and just as fast
```

- Fox[20]

will find the first fox and not the second.

What I am looking for is something like

- Fox[50] that won't start search until char 50 ("and he was crazy as a fox and just as fast")

Comment: One small point, the field position limit modifier works on the WORD position, not the character position. Nearly everything in sphinx works on WORDs (ala tokens), not individual characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you could say

```
"bla bla" @field[50] -"bla bla"
```

But you have the old problem of it also exlcuding items with it after as well as before.

<s>Otherwise think you will have to look at ranking expressions, there is `min_hit_pos` which can use. Would have to use the ranking expression to change the ranking calculation, and then 'post filter' based on the weight. Can use the weight in WHERE, via virtual attributes.</s>
(this wont work either, see comments!)

Comment: Assuming I can't do this with SphinxQL to test but my understanding none-the-less is that I'd do my search for say 'fox' w/o any field-position-limit since that only limits the farthest out the match can be not where to start, and then AFTER I get my match(es) refer to the min_hit_pos and I'd have some code that would then qualify based in whatever I decided it should be (e.g. 300 Words)?

Comment: In the example above however wouldn't min_hit_pos return the first fox anyway which is precisely what I am trying to avoid?

Comment: good point, min_hit_pos, would have the same issue. You would need max_hit_pos. To make sure that is bigger than your cutoff. Alas sphinx doesnt have one!

Comment: This seems a major limitation. There must be countless situations where one needs to search after a certain point in a doc not before. Or even search from back to front? My only thoughts now are either to run some reverse words in string/document but that becomes a massive chore on 100s of 1000s of docs. Option B is to extract a new field with say Char300-N using Mysql and actually store it like that. Again these both seem like highly inefficient solutions for an engine that seems like it should have this native capability.

Comment: This is probably not that common a requirement. Honestly this is the first time I've ever seen someone asking about this, in several years of answering sphinx questions.

Comment: Hmm, as it happens, now a similar question has now turned up! http://sphinxsearch.com/forum/view.html?id=13996